# Spring: bean conflict with existing non-compatible bean

Tags: spring, tomcat

Our project uses spring 2.5.5 and Tomcat. I have just migrated tomcat from 5.5 to 7. But when tomcat loads webapp context, we get this exception . 
It seems spring scanned all the same components at least twice. Has anybody met this exception before?

```
Aug 16, 2012 1:54:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Aug 16, 2012 1:54:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [spring-configuration/application-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Annotation-specified bean name 'observerLockMonitor' for bean class [aaa.aaa.ObserverLockMonitor] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class[aaa.aaa.ObserverLockMonitor]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:420)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:353)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:963)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1600)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Annotation-specified bean name 'observerLockMonitor' for bean class [aaa.aaa.ObserverLockMonitor]conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [aaa.aaa.ObserverLockMonitor]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.checkCandidate(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:267)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:208)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:85)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:69)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1255)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1245)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:92)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:507)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
... 27 more
```

The web.xml under WEB-INF is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath*:spring-configuration/*.xml; 
            classpath*:spring-configuration/${apollo.realm}/${apollo.domain}/*.xml; 
            classpath*:spring-configuration/${apollo.realm}/*.xml  
        </param-value>

    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>rds-eventProcessor</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>rds-eventProcessor</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- 
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ping</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            amazon.rds.processor.utils.VipHealthCheck
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ping</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ping/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    -->
</web-app>
```

One of xml under classpath is application-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd "
       default-destroy-method="shutdown">

  <context:annotation-config />


    <context:component-scan base-package="aaa.aaa" />  
    <context:component-scan base-package="bbb.bbb" />  
    <context:component-scan base-package="ccc.ccc" />

...... here we have some other beans that are defined manually.
</beans>
```

The beans definition is :

```
@Component
public class ObserverLockMonitor implements RDSAlfSessionDroppedListener {
    public interface RDSAlfSessionStartedListener {
        public void sessionStarted(AlfConnection alfConnection);
    }

    private static EventLog log = EventLogFactory.getEventLog(ObserverLockMonitor.class);

    private final RDSAlfConnectionFactory alfConnectionFactory;
    private final List<RDSAlfSessionStartedListener> sessionStartedListeners;

    /**
     * Timestamp of the last time we had a valid connection to alf...
     */
    private Long timeOfLastSeenAlfConnection = System.currentTimeMillis();

    private AlfConnection alfConnection;

    @Autowired
    public ObserverLockMonitor(RDSAlfConnectionFactory alfConnectionFactory, List<RDSAlfSessionStartedListener> sessionStartedListeners) {
        this.alfConnectionFactory = alfConnectionFactory;
        this.sessionStartedListeners = sessionStartedListeners;
    }
```

Any hints or pointers would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide your web.xml and Spring appplication context XML?

Comment: @steve.hanson Thank you for your reply. I have added these two xmls.

Comment: what are the annotations on the bean?

Comment: @chrislovecnm I have updated the source code above. Thank you :)

Comment: @user1607834 I need to see the bean annotations ... java code please

Comment: Put spring in debug mode and check logs.

Are you sure your have looked at the root stacktrace ? Check catalina.out

Comment: @chrislovecnm I have added the bean definition. Thanks.

Comment: @user1607834 may be nothing but have your tried moving the interface definition to another java file?  Also what happens if you add Component("observerTest") instead of Component.  Also debug logging?

Comment: @chrislovecnm if I add Component("observerTest"), I still get the same exception. When I switch to spring debug logging, I find that springframework resolved 2 locations:one is /WEB-INF, the other one is jar file. Can this be the root cause?

Comment: Yep.  Why do you have two classes?

Comment: @chrislovecnm I don't know why. Spring loads these two locations automaticlly. Should I prevent spring loading the jar file? Thanks.

Comment: do you have a jar and a .class deployed separately?

Comment: @chrislovecnm I only have the .class deployed, i use another package called "TomcatWebappLoader" to load dependencies of my webapp.